How to modify Pods IP address in EKS
I know my next question kind of anti-pattern in kubernetes but I have no choice.
I am deploying my app in EKS. My app gets HTTP requests from a UI pod in my cluster and looks at the source IP and allows it to access my back end in the pod ( tomcat )  only if the IP of the UI pod is in an allowed IP list which resides in a database pod.
This means that every restart of the UI pod I gets a different IP and my app cannot get any more HTTP requests.
Do you have any solution suggestion on how I can accomplish or mimic and option for a static IP for a pod or adlist modify the source-ip ?
I tried moving the traffic via internal Nginx but that did not work.
I know there is an option to put a init-container in my UI pod , check the IP and put it in the database , but I really prefer not to go this path.
I also tried passing the traffic via services, but the back end pod still recognizes the UI pod source IP.

Is the application itself visible to the public Internet (through a LoadBalancer-type Service or an Ingress), or does it always receive requests proxied via the UI container?  If it's not accessible from outside the cluster, it doesn't seem like you need this IP ACLing at all.

You can use a StatefulSet if you want to have a stable identity for your Pods.
Perhaps it is a better idea to re-think the authorization in use, though.
